# Should I wake my infant to feed?

Tags: newborn, breastfeeding, babyfood

My two month old son is overweight according to our pediatrician (6.1kg/13.5 lb), and the pediatrician advised us to give him 4 ounces of milk every 2 hours in order to manage his weight.

Sometimes, he sleeps for 3-4 hours at a time.  Is it okay to feed him after 3-4 hour sleep, or should we follow the 2 hour interval and wake him up?

Comment: What does your pediatrician say?

Comment: How many kg was your baby when he was born?

Comment: Edited to be on topic (to make clear that you're asking for help with the sleep time issue as opposed to the amount fed).  Answers *must* address this , and not address the amount fed, or they will be deleted; we cannot advise people to go against pediatrician advice.

Comment: Since we can't supersede your pediatrician's advice, ask your pediatrician to clarify.

Comment: 4oz of milk every 2 hours is 48oz in a day!  That doesn't sound at all correct, there is no way any baby of that size can drink this much in a day.  You should probably ask for clarification from your pediatrician.  As a good rule of thumb, you should feed 2.5oz of formula per pound of baby.  That is around 33oz a day, which still seems quite high given the age.

Comment: @Stacey he weight 3.6kg.

Comment: By the way, according to the WHO child growth standard, 6.1 kg at 2 month isn't overweight. You can look up the charts here: https://www.who.int/childgrowth/standards/weight_for_age/en/

Answer (score 6):

The advice at the hospital where I gave birth was that you let babys sleep unless they are underweight or have some other medical condition that makes it necessary to wake them. Healthy babys will let you know when they are hungry.

Also, in my very limited experience, waking/feeding the baby on a schedule can get them so used to that schedule that they're going to stick to it even when they could sleep longer, while letting the baby decide when it's hungry can get you more rest at night sooner.

BUT, ask your baby's pediatrician or your midwife if you are at all unsure. They are the ones that know your baby and can give medical advice that fits to your situation.